The "featuretype" argument seems to be not working in geopy package. Any idea why?
I have a dataframe of locations which I'd like to get the coordinates of. To do so, I'm using the geopy package and the Nominatim API. Although I have specified the featuretype argument to return only the cities, settlements and villages, it still gives me coordinates of highways, buildings and other unrelated stuff. The rest of the code just works fine but I need to be accurate with the coordinates as it is a list of locations throughout the whole country. Below is a snippet of the geolocator I'm using.
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="my_geocoder", timeout=None)
location = geolocator.geocode(place_name, extratags=True, 
featuretype=['state', 'city', 'settlement', 'village'])

Thank you for your help!
Edit: Found a workaround with a blunt force function. However, I'd still appreciate it if there is a more robust and flexible solution. Here is the snippet for the function I came up with:
def filter_locations(results):
    desired_types = ['city', 'town', 'village', 'hamlet', 'suburb', 'neighbourhood', 'residential']
    desired_classes = ['place', 'boundary', 'administrative']
    filtered_results = [result for result in results if result['type'] in desired_types or result['class'] in desired_classes]
    return filtered_results

